# Исходный код

Tags: javascript

Если я не ошибаюсь, javascript - это браузерный язык. Так как узнать исходный javascript код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript, как следует из названия, это Скриптовый язык, интерпретируемый JS движком. И у каждого движка - свои способы интерпритации... V8 ( Google Chrome ), клянуться что переводят его в машинные коды ( JIT компиляция ). Как у других -  не подскажу

Comment: Ой что то  я тупанул  ,все я понял как узнать .Спасибо Сергей

Answer (score 2):

**`Ctrl-U`** .